# How to show ToolTips on Values of DropDown Box in Classic ASP?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp-classic

Is it possible to show Tool Tip on DropDown Values befor selection one from DropDown, using Classic ASP?

Please let me know if there is any solution.

Thanks,
Suman.

Answer (score 2):

ASP runs on the server-side, so there's nothing you can do to add that functionality with ASP.  Additionally, I don't think it's something that any browser supports with just HTML/CSS either.

So that leaves you with JavaScript.  [Here's a post I found with Google](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t101413-dropdown-list-show-tool-tip.html) with something that sounds very similar to what you want to do.